# Uploading code of django to github repository in ubuntu

Tags: django, git, github, repository, ubuntu-14.04

I have this little problem regarding to upload my existing django project to github repository.
This is my working directory and here my django code stays.

```
mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_mj/django_test$ ls -l
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 4 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat  4096 Aug 27 05:31 article
-rw-r--r-- 1 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat 34816 Aug 26 21:42 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x 2 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat  4096 Aug 27 06:35 django_test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat   254 Aug 25 18:09 manage.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat     0 Aug 27 06:46 README.md
drwxrwxr-x 4 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat  4096 Aug 27 05:35 static
drwxrwxr-x 2 mjrulesamrat mjrulesamrat  4096 Aug 27 05:33 templates
```

Now when i try to add or commit it says following msg.

```
mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_mj/django_test$ git add .
mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_mj/django_test$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_mj/django_test$ git commit -m "app_commit_no_4"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
mjrulesamrat@mjrulesamrat-Lenovo-G570:~/django_mj/django_test$
```

Please help me upload code to my repository.

Comment: do you have created empty project for these code in github?

Comment: Is it the initial checkin? Did you forget `git init` ?

Comment: no i didn't forget
    git init
and i have created new repository on github website.

Comment: Why someone downgrade my question..?
I'm really facing this problem. My project is still not commited to my repository on github. Help me please.

Comment: @bekt I don't understand what you are saying.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I have made changes on the remote repository.
That's why it was giving me error.
So, first i have to pull the changes from the remote repository and then i have to push the changes.
These are the commands that I followed.
I learned from my sir later.

```
git pull remote_repo
git add .
git status
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

This works good till date.

Answer (score 1):

to upload my code to github repository, I usually create my project on github first.

1. clone my project to my PC with `git clone https://github.com/myusername/myproject.git`
2. copy - paste to my code to cloned project.
3. run `git add .`
4. run `git commit -am 'this is msg'`
5. run `git push origin master`

Comment: Thank you @bekt.
I forgot to clone the project first.